# Is there a way to manage the number of records returned by the localbitcoin API?

Tags: php

```
$prefix = 'sell';
    $localbtc = 'https://localbitcoins.com/'.$prefix.'-bitcoins-online/vef/.json';
    $localbtc_page2 = $localbtc.'?page=2';
  $content_page1 = fgc($localbtc);
 $content_page2 = fgc($localbtc_page2);
```

I am making a request to get the json, however the data is quite large and it takes a few seconds, is there a way to recover a few records? like 50 0 60?

Comment: If its not here, then it's nowhere https://localbitcoins.com/api-docs/

Comment: From documentation: `It is not possible to configure the maximum amount of items returned at a time.`
You can choose only fields that you need to not load them all, and improve response time.

Comment: do you know any way to get the records without it taking so long?

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `?fields=field_name_1,field_name_2,field_name_3,field_name_n` and enumerate only fields that you need from the response.